# Rails App Upgrade from 2.3.14 to 4 Errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-2

I am trying to upgrade my rails 2.3.14 app to rails 4 but experiencing some issues.

In my `routes.rb` I have the following general rules defined after the more specific ones:

```
map.connect ':controller/:action/:id'
map.connect ':controller/:action/:id/:org'
map.connect ':controller/:action/:id.:format'  

map.connect ':action/:id', :controller => "home"
```

so in the rails 4 equivalent I changed these to

```
get  ':controller/:action/:id'
get  ':controller/:action/:id/:org'
get  ':controller/:action/:id.:format'  

get  ':action/:id', :controller => "home"
```

`http://localhost:3000/` is still taking me to the default home page, I assume it's because there's no `root 'welcome#index'` (example from `routes.rb` file) route but I'm not sure how to achieve that since in my app the home url is defined like so in `application_controller.rb`

```
def default_home_url
  if @person
    '/ticket/list/Open'
  elsif request.env["HTTP_REFERER"].include? 'portal'
  '/portal'
  else
    "/"
  end
end
```

The `home_controller.rb #index` is

```
def index
  redirect_to default_home_url if @person
end
```

and the way that `@person` is set is in a function named `check_user` in the `application_controller.rb`

```
def check_user
 @person = Person.find(session[:person]) if session[:person]
 @admin = (@person and @person.priviledges == 'admin')
end
```

This function is called when someone logs in and at the top of `application_controller.rb`.

So, if I go to `http://localhost:3000/ticket/list/Open` in the rails 4 app I get this error: `NoMethodError in TicketController#list` `undefined method 'include?' for nil:NilClass` and the line highlighted is this one:

```
elsif request.env["HTTP_REFERER"].include? 'portal'
```

from `application_controller.rb`, not `ticket_controller.rb` so I am thoroughly confused about what's going on.

Apologies if anything is unclear, I can provide more information if needed.

**update**

Managed to get rid of the error by changing that line to

```
elsif request.env.try(:include?, 'portal')
```

so the home url is still taking me to the default rails homepage.

Answer (score 0):

managed to solve it, was quite straightforward in the end, just needed the following route:

```
root 'home#index'
```